# Doctrine see old Entities after migrating

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration

I have a domain www.mydomain.com where is installed a web app perfectly working.
I had to create a third level domain test.mydomain.com where I copied all the file of my web app included all the doctrine files.
I don't think I need to explain what test will be used to...anyway, after migrating my entire project and applied some modifications to the entities when I launch the command:

```
php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
```

In the generated queries, the old entities from the production project are shown instead of the modified ones.
I deleted all the cache with the following commands:

```
php doctrine orm:clear-cache:query --flush
php doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata --flush
php doctrine orm:clear-cache:result --flush
php doctrine orm:clear-cache:query
php doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
php doctrine orm:clear-cache:result
```

It didn't work. The connection with the DB is good and also the credentials work fine I've already tested this. It doesn't work the update and create schema commands.

Any advises?

Answer (score 0):

In the file cli-config.php there were a constant which pointed in the production server folder. Once updated the path everything worked fine.